# Image Viewpager issue on android Nougat

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have an image view pager that slides automatically that works fine on all android operating systems, or that what i thought. I was surprised that the sliding on nougat is so wrong and the images are loaded with each other and everything is wrong, does anybody know why?

Here's the adapter:

```
private class AdsPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private ArrayList<Advertisments> allAds;

    public AdsPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Advertisments> allAds) {
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.allAds = allAds;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return allAds.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ad_pager_item, container, false);

        final ImageView ivAd = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivAd);
        try {
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load("http://www.almowazi.com/Temp/Ads/" + allAds.get(position).getImageUrl())
                    .into(ivAd, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            //do smth when picture is loaded successfully
                            ivAd.setAlpha((float) 1);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                            //progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            //do smth when there is picture loading error
                        }
                    });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ivAd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(allAds.get(position).getUrl())));
            }
        });

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }
}
```

here's the sliding code:

```
try {

            pagerAdapterAds.notifyDataSetChanged();
            NUM_PAGES = allAds.size();
            final Handler handler2 = new Handler();

            final Runnable Update2 = new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    if (currentAdsPage == NUM_PAGES - 1) {
                        currentAdsPage = -1;
                    }
                    pagerAds.setCurrentItem(currentAdsPage++, true);

                }
            };

            Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
            swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    handler2.post(Update2);
                }
            }, 1000, 4000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

here's a screenshot on a lollipop device:
[lollipop device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7hgl.jpg)

Here's a screenshot on a nougat device:

[nougat device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/575wF.png)